# Is there any possibility in pie3D (package plotrix) to connect the labels with the chart?

Tags: r, pie-chart, plotrix

I want to connect my value Label with the pie Chart. I am using pie3D, but didn't find any Option. 
Here my current code and the pie Chart I get:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,2))
for (i in seq_along(vec1)){
#Data for pie
#select the column i of varcomp
r<- subset(varcomp, select=vec1[i])
r1<-r[6:13,]


#for displaying percentage values 
piepercent<- round(100*r1/sum(r1), 1)
piepercent<-round(piepercent, digits=0)

p<-pie3D(#data for pie
r1,
#specify labels vector
#labels=piepercent,
#specify labels size
labelcex=0.9,
#how much different pies go from each other
explode=0.1,
#height of chart
height=0.1,
#Main title
theta=pi/3,
#Colors
col=colors,
main=c("Variance Components",paste(vec1[i])))

pie3D.labels(p,labels=piepercent,labelcex=1,labelrad=1.8)
}
```

[image: graph I get]

[image: Graph I want]

Comment: It seems it's missing some parts of the code, for example `vec1` e the `}` in the end of the for loop.

Comment: thank you, you are right, I forgot to copy it. I just edited it.

Comment: Anyone who can answer this?